# Getting "_Static_assert is a C11-specific feature" with -std=c99 on FreeBSD

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, freebsd

Reduced to simplest reproducible size:

```c
#include <assert.h>

#ifdef static_assert
static_assert(1 == 1, "oops!");
#endif
```

compiled with `-std=c99 -pedantic` gives `warning: _Static_assert is a C11-specific feature [-Wc11-extensions]` on FreeBSD (tested on 11.2 and 12.3, which use clang 6.0 and 10.0 respectively).

I don't get this problem on Linux (`static_assert` does not get defined when `std=c99` is specified) with either gcc or clang (various versions).

The `#ifdef` guard is specifically to avoid the problem of trying to use a C11 feature when it's not available!

(As I said, this is the smallest reproducible size. Actually I want to define my own `static_assert` if there's not one available, and have the source code compile cleanly on as many systems as possible.)

On FreeBSD, `assert.h` defines `static_assert` if `__ISO_C_VISIBLE >= 2011`.  `__ISO_C_VISIBLE` is being set by default in `sys/cdefs.h`.

On Linux, `assert.h` defines `static_assert` if `__USE_ISOC11` is defined, and `__USE_ISOC11` is defined by `features.h` if `_ISOC11_SOURCE` is defined.

I'm somewhat surprised that `__STDC_VERSION__` is not being checked on FreeBSD (the Linux version will define `static_assert` if `__STDC_VERSION__ >= 201112L`).  But on both I'm somewhat surprised that a lower value of `__STDC_VERSION__` isn't being used to restrict the feature.

I can work around this with some FreeBSD-specific checks, but is FreeBSD doing it "wrong" or is Linux doing it "wrong"?

Comment: It doesn't much matter which is correct.  What happens is what happens.  You will have to work out whether you can deal with what you have found.  Even if FreeBSD accepts a bug report and fixes it in the next release, it will be years before the problem is no longer present in the wild.

Comment: What is `__ISO_C_VISIBLE` set to on FreeBSD?  Presumably 2011 or 2018.  The name is reserved for the implementation so it is probably not something you can tamper with.  Why do you need to compile with C99 mode on FreeBSD anyway?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, OP might need a solution now, but that does not mean which is correct does not matter. Knowing which is correct tells you which to file a bug report against. Knowing which is correct informs you about what solution to implement now, e.g., to correct to the FreeBSD way of doing things or to correct to the Linux way of doing things.

Comment: I guess you could suppress it by defining `_POSIX_C_SOURCE` to `200112L` or `200809L`, or by defining `_XOPEN_SOURCE` to `600` or `700`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Both FreeBSD 11.2 and 12.3 define `__ISO_C_VISIBLE` to `2011` in `sys/cdefs.h` whether the compile is invoked with `-std=c99` or not (no other defines etc on command line)

Comment: Under what conditions would `_C99_SOURCE` get set?

Comment: @jxh `_C99_SOURCE` is never defined by the headers on a standard install, so it must be there to be set by the user. The comment by the check `#if defined(_C99_SOURCE)` says *Localism to specify strict c99 env*. Which is kind of what `-std=c99 -pedantic` is saying. `_C99_SOURCE` is also tested by Xcode on macOS, but ignored completely on Linux (Ubuntu with clang and/or gcc).

Comment: I believe `_C99_SOURCE` would be something FreeBSD specific then, and you would  provide your own localization tests to check FreeBSD and set it in your C99 source files.

Answer (score 1):

> I can work around this with some FreeBSD-specific checks, but is
> FreeBSD doing it "wrong" or is Linux doing it "wrong"?

The default compiler for FreeBSD is clang and the default for Linux is gcc.
In the case of FreeBSD, clang is used for the base system and uses a custom crafted Makefile authored by FreeBSD.

I also tested this on macOS which is a FreeBSD derived OS. It worked as expected.

FreeBSD's clang seems to have a deviation. Whether or not it is a bug or intentionally needed to build the base system correctly, I do not know.

So in a strict answer to your question, FreeBSD is doing something wrong here.

Clang 13.0.0 on FreeBSD-13.1:

```
% cc -std=c99 -pedantic -o m m.c
m.c:4:1: warning: '_Static_assert' is a C11 extension [-Wc11-extensions]
```